# The benefits of CISSP Training for a Java developer

Tags: java, cissp

I am currently a Java developer and content with what I make. My company currently offers a 7 Day CISSP training and I am not sure, whether to take this training.

What benefits can I benefit by taking this training or it would be just a time consuming activity to take this training in my case?

Comment: If you don't take the CISSP training, are there other courses on offer?

Comment: @paj28 do you mean other IT security related courses or any other couses. There is no IT-Security related couses, but on different dates, there are other courses but not comprehensive like this one.

Comment: I meant any other. What I was getting at is if your choice is "CISSP or nothing" then take CISSP - learning is always good. But if you're taking CISSP at the cost of something else, well, it depends on the "something else" but I suspect CISSP wouldn't be for you.

Comment: At the moment, the selection is like "CISSP or nothing" but each training costs money for my company and in the near future, when there is a more related training, which I can take, it would be more difficult to say, I want to take also this one. That is why, I asked here, whether i should take or not.

Comment: In that case, skip CISSP and do a more relevant course in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're aiming for. The CISSP is said to cover topics "one mile long, one inch thick", so it's everything from malware, organizational stuff, disaster recovery, cryptography, physical security (which fire extinctors for which fires), identity management, even secure deveopment and testing. So it's veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery broad but every topic is covered pretty superficially.
So if you're aiming for a security career then it is a helpful asset, definitely. But if you are more a technical guy and you want to stay technical then I would do something where you can develop a rare technical competence. the CISSP training book has more than 900 pages. If you want to get the certification you REALLY REALLY need to spend a lot of time on this stuff (I doubt a one week training will be enough).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just want to advance in my own career and do not think to change it. However, because of the fact that I do not know literally nothing about the CISSP, I wanted to learn if taking such a training brings me something. However, from your answer, I understood that it will not or?

Comment: Yes, if you want to stay in development then at least 80% of what they teach is irrelevant.